# Append an object to an array inside a nested object

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I have a collection in MongoDB in which one of the documents looks like this:

```
{
  _id: ObjectId("6162883719592ea3350d3c87"),
  fullName: 'Random User',
  username: 'ruser1',
  password: 'asdadasd',
  portfolio: [ { equity: [] }, { crypto: [] }, { etf: [] }, { cash: [] } ]
}
```

I am trying to append a new object of the following format to the `equity` array inside the `portfolio`.

Object format:

```
{
  name : "AAPL",
  quantity : 1,
  price : 100
}
```

I was trying to use the `$push` to do this operation, but I'm encountering the following error:

```
db.users.updateOne( 
  {_id : ObjectId("6162883719592ea3350d3c87")},
  {$push : {"portfolio.equity" : {
    name : "AAPL",
    quantity : 1,
    price : 100
    }
  }
 }
)
```

> MongoServerError: Cannot create field 'equity' in element {portfolio: [ { equity: [] }, { crypto: [] }, { etf: [] }, { cash: [] } ]}

I have also tried to use `portfolio.$.equity`, but that did not work either.

```
db.users.updateOne(
  {_id : ObjectId("6162883719592ea3350d3c87")} , 
  {$push : {"portfolio.$.equity" : {name : "AAPL", price : 100, quantity : 1}}}
)
```

> MongoServerError: The positional operator did not find the match needed from the query.

In short, I am trying to append an object to an array inside an object's object.

How can I resolve this error or what is the appropriate way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`arrayFilters`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/#std-label-update-array-filters) with check `portfolio.equity` field is existed via [`$exists`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/exists/).

```
db.users.updateOne({
  _id: ObjectId("6162883719592ea3350d3c87")
},
{
  $push: {
    "portfolio.$[portfolio].equity": {
      name: "AAPL",
      price: 100,
      quantity: 1
    }
  }
},
{
  arrayFilters: [
    {
      "portfolio.equity": {
        $exists: true
      }
    }
  ]
})
```

[Sample Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/pQBH0JAHSZO)

Comment: Didnt know mongoplayground exists, and that you can do such complex operations that easy. Thanks :)

Comment: @Yong Shun I appreciate your answer, but can you explain why do we have to use array filters? Why can't we directly push an object in the array?

Comment: `portfolio` is an array. So `portfolio.equity` is invalid. `arrayFilters` is used to traverse the documents in the array with condition. For your case, as `equity` field is only existed in one document, so you need to filter the document which contains `equity` field. If you do `$push` with `portfolio.$[].equity`, all the documents in `portfolio` will be created new `equity` field.